# General Relativity in the absence of observers

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, observers

I see that just as in quantum mechanics, General Relativity is depending on observations taking place, hence they are depending on the existence of an information carrier which are photons, virtual or real. My question is, what do you think: does gravity exist when there are absolutely no observers around? If we let an electron free around a massive body, without keeping observing it, how can we be sure it will follow a geodesic and not just ignore that and move away freely? And if we keep observing it, we'll induce anyway a Zeno effect on it. Also, if I am inside a space station, I will never be able to observe I am in orbit of a planet if I do not receive some external fotons on my retina to "confirm" to me my actual situation.
So, are fotons and observation necessary for space-time curvature to exist?

Comment: GR is not observer-dependent.  The term 'observer' is used just to answer the question of what a sufficiently light measurement device with a good clock would record if it followed a particular timelike curve.

Comment: Does the universe exist if there are no observers?

Comment: In special relativity, an observer is a frame of reference from which a set of objects or events are being measured. Usually this is an inertial reference frame or "inertial observer". (Wikipedia)  So measurement IS important for deducing curvature. And measurement means particles interacting and wave functions collapsing. What I am asking is, again, does measurement determine to some extent the space-time curvature ?

Comment: I've always wondered whether space must be observed to have entropy.

Comment: We enter here the antropic principle or the fine tuning for life of the Universe. Both very interesting ideas. I think, that the space-time is made of an infinity of quantum observers and that Relativity is a very much inflated and washed out version of the quantum uncertainty, because they both need someone to make an experiment. It doesn't matter that in relativity the observers are some rulers and cameras and clocks, as long as all the gathered data from these rulers and clocks will be ultimately used and interpreted by human observers.

Comment: But if we want to keep ourselves "sane" we better keep track with the mainstream version of the events too. This is why I am here. To stand on the boundary of magic and hardcore science, hoping to find something fantastic.

Comment: At a very very fundamental level, there is no entropy!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. If I am correct, in relativity, the word observer means a reference point. An observer doesn't mean a human who's observing what is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, let's assume that "observer" means "frame of reference," which is the way you defined it in the comments.

**"Does gravity exist when there are no observers around?"**

There is no physical situation where there are no frames of reference around, so this question is moot.

**"If we let an electron free around a massive body, without keeping observing it, how can we be sure it will follow a geodesic and not just ignore that and move away freely?"**

If you're talking about general relativity, which is a classical theory that treats electrons as classical particles, then we can be sure the electron, like everything else, will follow a geodesic. Doing quantum mechanics in curved space is tricky, but the expectation values for observables for free particles still follow geodesics.

**"Also, if I am inside a space station, I will never be able to observe I am in orbit of a planet if I do not receive some external fotons on my retina to "confirm" to me my actual situation."**

An extended object orbiting a planet is acted upon by tidal forces. You could in principle feel these tidal forces acting on your own body, and confirm not only that you were in orbit around a planet, but also infer the current direction of the planet. Not a single photon needs to enter your eye to do this.

**"So, are fotons and observation necessary for space-time curvature to exist?"**

No.

Comment: Nice answer. This phrase is useful :  "expectation values for observables for free particles still follow geodesics."  Tidal forces are felt because of electromagnetic forces trying to keep the test body in one piece. If we could shut those down, no gravity would be felt. I know the space-time metric is not uniquely defined and for every Feynamn path there must be a given metric with a certain action. So, observation is making the metric to collapse too...so there is a slight probability also for escaping the geodesic.  Thank you anyway, I'll  conceive more coherent questions from now on.

Comment: I would advise that you learn more about QFT before you start speculating about quantum gravity. It's a bit more complicated than you realize, and doesn't really involve the presence of an observer in any way.

Comment: I will take into consideration your advice. Perhaps spontaneous or self-induced decoherence makes the presence of observers futile. I am familiar with the apparition of mass terms due to symmetry breaking, I can relate to what you said. Just that, as it happens with anybody, it is hard to keep the classical part and the quantum part separated in the same brain. The mind wants to know things between which it can make connections, and when it fails there is a problem. I just tried to push the boundaries a little.